# $location.path not binding the data in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have two angular js controllers. When the click the ng-href link in recorddetails.html,
I am able to see the result binded as "The activity name is Exercise" but the same if I do with ng-click by clicking button with find() in send.html. I am able to see the recorddetails.html but the page is displaying without the data being binded as "The activity name is {{activity}}".I have provided the code belowe for reference.Kindly, provide some valuable solutions.

**index.html**

```
            <div ng-controller="controllerOne">
            <a ng-href="#/recorddetails/100">Running</a> 
          </div>
```

**recorddetails.html**

```
        <div ng-controller="controllerTwo">
            <p> The activity name is {{activity}}</a>// The scope name is Exercise 
          </div>
```

**send.html**

```
         <div ng-controller="controllerThree">
           <button ng-click="find()">
          </div>
```

**JS file**

```
          angular.module('exampleapp', ['ngRoute').config(
                [ '$provide', '$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', function($provide,               $httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider. 

                      when('/recorddetails/:id', {
                            templateUrl: '/records/recorddetails.html',
                            controller: 'controllerTwo'
                           .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/defaultpage'
                      });




            app.controller('controllerOne',
                [ '$scope','$location',function($scope,$location) {`enter code here`
                        }

            app.controller('controllerTwo',
                [ '$scope','$location',function($scope,$location) {
        $scope.activity = "Exercise";
                        }

   app.controller('controllerThree',
                [ '$scope','$location',function($scope,$location) {
$scope.find = function(){
        $location.path("/recorddetails/100");
                        }
}
```

Comment: try $location.path("#/recorddetails/100")

Comment: tried that buddy its redirecting to defaultpage.html

Comment: you are defining controller both at ngroute level and template level. If you specifying your controller for url at config level you don't need to write contoller name in template html file.

Comment: I removed that from the template and saw even though I got the same result.

Comment: Can you create plnkr or something?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app=angular.module('binding',['ngRoute'])
app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
            templateUrl:'one.html',
            controller:'controllerOne'
        })
        .when('/recorddetails/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'recorddetails.html',
            controller: 'controllerTwo'

        })
        .when('/send', {
            templateUrl: 'send.html',
            controller: 'controllerThree'

        })
}])






app.controller('controllerOne',function($scope,$location){

})

app.controller('controllerTwo', function($scope,$location) {
          
        $scope.activity = "Exercise";
                        })


   app.controller('controllerThree',function($scope,$location) {
$scope.find = function(){
    console.log('in 3');
        $location.path("/recorddetails/100");
                        }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="binding">

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="routefile.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-view>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```